# Error when login apple enterprise account in VS2022

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2022, maui, apple-developer, apple-developer-enterprise

I'm facing a really big problem.
I develope in VS2022 with a .net Maui application on my Windows 10 Laptop. Now I want to debug on my local iOS devices via .net Maui hot restart (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/maui/deployment/hot-restart?view=net-maui-7.0).

I have an enterprise account from my company which is declared as an app-manager:
[image]

First I tried to add my enterprise account in Options>Xamarin>Apple Accounts. I just typed my user data in nothing else. I didn't downloaded any key or anything else. I tried to add it but I get the following error message:
[image]

The first time I tried to add it, it wasn't the same. I got the window to enter my code which was send on my phone. But the progress was interrupt because of a bad internet connection.

I allready contaced the apple support about this but they said if I can login in App Store Connect its not their problem and I have to contact Microsoft about this. The problem: The VS support I found wasn't free...

Sometimes when I reopen the Apple Account window my Apple-Id gets listed and also as an enterprise account. The only problem there is no Team I can select and the View Details button is not selectable:
[image]

So my question: What am I supposed to do? I need this access to work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can manage certificates and profiles via Apples website.  You don’t have to do it from VS.  I’ve never done it that way

Comment: @Jason How do you mean this? can you please discribe it a littlebit more?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/manual-provisioning?tabs=macos

Comment: @Jason Just a question. You need a my host for this right?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about

Comment: All the steps under the point Add a device are made on a Mac. How am I supposed to do this with a Windows 10 Laptop?

Comment: you need a Mac to do any type of iOS development

Comment: @Jason it's possible to develope ios over Windows with hot restart: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/maui/deployment/hot-restart?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: I saw that you posted the same ['Error when login apple enterprise account in VS2022'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1124199/error-when-login-apple-enterprise-account-in-vs202.html) thread in Q&A, let's focus on that one.

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT That's correct. Thank you for your help. I allready answered your comment.

Comment: ok, waiting for your update in Q&A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits: Dongzhi Wang-MSFT

You must have to login with the account holder account from your organization. That worked for me.